# UI bootstrap datepicker not aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a UI-Bootstrap datepicker

```
 <div class="col-md-2">

    <label for="datepicker">Select Date<span class="compulsary">*</span></label><br>

     <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" id="datepicker"/>
     <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
     </span>

</div>
```

This is the css to the input field

```
#datepicker{
    height: 50px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

The calendar button appears beneath the input field, and not besides it, as if a `<br>` has been applied to it. I want the button to appear adjacent to the field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you make a working snippet please? Also show us a screenshot on how it looks so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) according to Bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-md-2">

    <label for="datepicker">Select Date<span class="compulsary">*</span></label><br>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" id="datepicker"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [horizontal forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal).

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="datepicker">Select Date<span class="compulsary">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" id="datepicker"/>
    </div>
</form>
```